# str.replace function raise error that an integer is required

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna ask the problem I encountered. At first, 
Let me show you my whole code

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(r'E:\내논문자료\골목상권 데이터\이태원로 54길 내용뺀거.xlsx' , sheetname='first_day_datas')
df1.registerdate= df1.registerdate.astype(str) # 칼럼 속성 바꾸기
df2 = pd.to_datetime(df1['registerdate'].str[0:10])
df3 = df2['registerdate'].str.replace('-', '').str.strip()
```

I just wanna change the string in registerdate column.
when I put print(df2.head(3)). It shows like below

```
0   2016-10-11
1   2016-10-15
2   2016-10-15
```

so I wanna replace '-' with ''. 
I type the code and 'TypeError: an integer is required' popped out.

Answer (score 2):

```
df2 = pd.to_datetime(df1['registerdate'].str[0:10])
#     \____________/
#    returns a series
```

---

```
df2['registerdate'].str.replace('-', '').str.strip()
#\_______________/
# is only something
# if 'registration
# is in the index
# this is probably the source of your error
```

---

At this point `df2` is a `pd.Series` of `Timestamps`.  the format `yyyy-mm-dd` is just the way that `Timestamp` is being displayed.  To display it as `yyyymmdd`, do this

```
df2.dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

0    20160331
1    20160401
2    20160402
3    20160403
4    20160404
Name: registerdate, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks~~ You are great guy~ Have a nice day~~

Answer (score 1):

It seems df2 has no column 'registerdate', It is a timestamp list.
I think `df2.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d')` can convert timestamp to the format you need.